# Shivopasana Mantra from Mahanarayana Upanishad

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, krishna-yajurveda, mahanarayana-upanishad

Is there any word-by-word meaning/translation that is available online of the Shivopasana Mantra from the Mahanarayana Upanishad?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://veda-gyan.blogspot.com/2018/05/sivopaasana-mantra-upasana-means-worship.html) is one that is of very high quality. Though it is technically a blog post, I checked the first few lines' translations using my own knowledge + [this](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate) tool, and they all look to be accurate. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: @ANGK - haha, no problem 